# Sort array into custom order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that I want sorted in an unconventional way.

```
[
  {
    type: 'web',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'graphics',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'UX',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'custom',
    id: 4
  }
]
```

How would I go about sorting this array by object.id so they appear in the order 1, 3, 4, 2 instead?

Comment: @falinsky: that answers a different question, but this question has definitely been asked before.  Let me look.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I apologize if that's the case, I was trying to look through similar questions but couldn't find the correct search term for it i guess.

Comment: @Oliver: It's not a big deal.  We close as duplicates so that there can be definitive answers to common questions, but it took me a bit of searching to find a correct duplicate, too.  Please let us know if neither one is a reasonable answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort` in javascript can use original function.

```js
arr=[
    {
      type: 'web',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      type: 'graphics',
      id: 2
    },
    {
      type: 'UX',
      id: 3
    },
    {
      type: 'custom',
      id: 4
    }
  ]

sort_key=[1,3,2,4]

arr.sort((a,b)=>sort_key.indexOf(a.id)-sort_key.indexOf(b.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `order` array for achieving this.

Creating a *dictionary* is more efficient than using `indexOf` method because the lookup for the dictionary is `O(1)`.

```js
var array = [ { type: 'web', id: 1 }, { type: 'graphics', id: 2 }, { type: 'UX', id: 3 }, { type: 'custom', id: 4 } ];

var order = [1, 3, 4, 2];
var orderDict =  order.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  acc[item] = index;
  return acc;
}, {});

array.sort((a, b) => orderDict[a.id] - orderDict[b.id]);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Yes, a dictionary will be more efficient... eventually.  But the size of the data is important too.  I'd be surprised if the costs of creating the dictionary are outweighed by the `O(n)` lookup in an array for a few entries or even a few dozen.  Be wary of premature optimizations.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, yes, creating dictionary is `O(n)` but `indexOf` has complexity `O(n)` because is unsorted array and it's executed many times while `sort` is executing.

Comment: But do you think that for the example of four items this would be more faster than the simpler `indexOf` answer?

Comment: For this small case, `indexOf` is faster. (https://jsbench.me/o4khoxzxiz/1)  I don't know where the break-even point would be.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, yes, you're right. For small case, `indexOf` is faster, but for large numbers https://jsbench.me/39khoygebu/1 the performance difference is huge and my approach wins.

Comment: Yes, that's all I was saying.  You can see in one of the duplicates that I was suggesting your approach, but if this case is as small as suggested, I would suggest the simpler code.